# How to scroll to a UIButton location in the UIScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have `UIButton` in `UIScrollView`,
I want to scroll to the location of this `UIButton` in the center of page at first time.

I know use `scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(X, Y), animated: true)`

but I don't know how to convert location of `UIButton` to X, Y

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a CGPoint variable based on where the UIButton is located within the scrollview:

```
 var buttonLocation = CGPointMake(button.bounds.origin.x, button.bounds.origin.y)
```

Then assign it to the contentOffset:

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(buttonLocation, animated: true)
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work, button.bounds.origin.x is always 0  :(

Comment: It should be `button.frame...`, not `button.bounds...` if you want the `UIButton`'s location in its `superview`.

Comment: you are right, but i need convert button.frame.origin.x to OFFSET, i dont know how to work :(

Comment: My mistake! Sometimes I get caught up and forget to proofread. Mike is right. 

With regard to your offset problem, you can set the function to move based on where the button is and also provide padding: CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x + 10, button.frame.origin.y + 10, animated: true).  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you don't understand my question :(

Answer (score 0):

```
// find the distance of the button from the center of the view
let deltaX = button.center.x - self.view.center.x
let deltaY = button.center.y - self.view.center.y

// change scrollView content offset based on the distance the button is from the center
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(deltaX, deltaY), animated: true)
```

Comment: Does the scroll view have enough content size so the button can be scrolled to the center of the view?  For example, if the scroll view content size is the same as the view size, then no scrolling can occur.  Similarly, if the button is at the top of the scroll view, then the scroll view cannot be scrolled down more to center the button, because there is no more content.

Answer (score 0):

make button an action when you control-drag it to your file then inside it put

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(x, y, w, h), animated: true)
```

example :

```
@IBAction func home(sender: AnyObject) {
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(x, y, w, h), animated: true)
    }
```